# no notification title animation when notification android created

Tags: android, notifications

I tried notification jelly bean. when the notification comes or created, only the first icon that appears in the status bar, no notification title animation ...

look this image, this display icon and title when created, but my notification just only icon .

[image]

this my code

```
 private static void generateNotification(Context context,String kat_pesan, String title, String message ,String judul,String  komentar,String  sekilas_isi,String 
             date,String gambar_tulisan_detail,String id_tulisan,String status_gambar, 
             String kategori, String main_kategori,String seo_detail,String pengomentar, String isi_komentar, String kordinat_lokasi, String username, String avatar) {
         long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int unique_ids=rand.nextInt();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


            Notification notification = null;
             notification = setBigTextStyleNotification(context,kat_pesan,title, message, judul,komentar, sekilas_isi,
                             date,gambar_tulisan_detail,id_tulisan,status_gambar,kategori,main_kategori,
                             seo_detail,pengomentar,isi_komentar, kordinat_lokasi, username,avatar,
                            when,unique_ids); 


            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

            // Play default notification sound
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

            //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

            // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            notification.number += 1;

            notificationManager.notify(unique_ids, notification);  

    }

private static Notification setBigTextStyleNotification(Context context, String kat_pesan, String title, String message, String judul, 
            String komentar, String sekilas_isi, String date, String gambar_tulisan_detail, String id_tulisan, String status_gambar, 
            String kategori, String main_kategori, String seo_detail, String pengomentar, String isi_komentar, String kordinat_lokasi, 
            String username, String avatar, long when, int unique_ids) {
        Bitmap remote_picture = null;

        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle notiStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        notiStyle.setBigContentTitle(judul);

        remote_picture = getBitmapFromURL(gambar_tulisan_detail);

        notiStyle.bigText(sekilas_isi);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, DetailIsi.class); 
        resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

        stackBuilder.addParentStack(DetailIsi.class);

        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(unique_ids, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
               .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notification)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setLargeIcon(remote_picture)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
              .addAction(0, "Open Detail", resultPendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle("#"+main_kategori+" #"+kategori)
                .setContentText(judul)
                .setStyle(notiStyle).build();
    }
```

how to fix it ? thanks, sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the ticker:

[NotificationCompat.Builder.setTicker(CharSequence tickerText)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setTicker%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Try this:

```
return new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notification)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setLargeIcon(remote_picture)
    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
    .addAction(0, "Open Detail", resultPendingIntent)
    .setContentTitle("#"+main_kategori+" #"+kategori)
    .setContentText(judul)
    .setTicker(judul)
    .setStyle(notiStyle).build();
```